# Visual Studio Code golang extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why does VSC randomly show these messages? I have a Go extension installed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `go` extension is trying to run the `godef` command without it being availiable.** That's why you see `Source: Go (extension)`.

The message has probably disappeared by now, but you can bring it back up and install the required command as follows.

- Click on the notification icon in the bottom bar.

[image]

- You should be able to see your recent notifications, find the `go` notification and select `'Install All'`

**This should stop the errors and notifications.**